# Cursor not changing to beam in insert mode when using Kitty terminal

Tags: insert-mode, cursor

Well the common problem again.

I could fix my problem for Konsole by adding

```
" Fix cursor for Konsole
let &t_SI = "\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=1\x7"
let &t_EI = "\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=0\x7"
```

to my .vimrc. This doesn't work for Kitty though. Has anyone fixed this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Try this](https://github.com/kovidgoyal/kitty/issues/2045#issuecomment-714295572):

```
let &t_SI = "\<Esc>[6 q"
let &t_SR = "\<Esc>[4 q"
let &t_EI = "\<Esc>[2 q"
```